# Jenkins fails to start Chrome

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am working on Jenkins to run my scripts but I am facing the following issue:

> Running TestSuite Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124
>   (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 7652 Only local
>   connections are allowed. log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for
>   logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies). log4j:WARN
>   Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed
>   to start: exited abnormally   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124
>   (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux
>   3.2.0-29-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.44 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30
>   11:02:44' System info: host: 'hb-Veriton-Series', ip: '127.0.1.1',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-29-generic',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_55' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:148)
>     at com.hb.MFA.BaseClass.getDriver(BaseClass.java:146)   at
>   com.hb.MFA.BaseClass.configureDriver(BaseClass.java:44)   at
>   com.hb.MFA.DSW.setUp(DSW.java:14)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
>   EXCEPTION ::: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124
>   (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux
>   3.2.0-29-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.44 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30
>   11:02:44' System info: host: 'hb-Veriton-Series', ip: '127.0.1.1',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-29-generic',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_55' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.hb.Utility.Util.getscreenshot(Util.java:86)  at
>   com.hb.MFA.DSW.run(DSW.java:58)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
>   Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 62.704
>   sec <<< FAILURE! run(com.hb.MFA.DSW)  Time elapsed: 0.322 sec  <<<
>   FAILURE! java.lang.AssertionError: null   at
>   org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)    at
>   com.hb.MFA.DSW.run(DSW.java:64)

NOTE :: This was arising when I run jenkins on ubuntu server,when I run on windows mechaine everything was fine

Comment: you've got a NPE at com.hb.Utility.Util.getscreenshot(Util.java:86). What's done here?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error by doing the following steps :-

1.Stop the jenkins service with the command - sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start

2.Run Jenkins manually with the following command from command line/terminal :-

java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war –httpPort=8080

This solution is for Ubuntu 14.04 version. Windows OS needs to handle the different paths but essentially the solution should work

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the DISPLAY parameter to your Jenkins job?

By default Jenkins will try to run in headless mode. You need to setup Xvfb and pass the DISPLAY number to your job.

---

**To add the the DISPLAY property**

In you jenkins settings add a global property

key: DISPLAY

value: 0:0

On your server start Xvfb in the background:

Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

Comment: YES. I did but no luck.I am still facing the same issue

Comment: can you attach a log file?  The error above is normally cause by what i highlighted, a log may help point to other potential issues.

Comment: Please refer to this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri

Comment: @JustARandomGuy, I have installed latest chromedriver,chrome browser,java (1.7 &1.6).I am able to run the script successfully through the terminal but jenkins fails to load the browser with same code and same configuration .Main thing is I was running jenkins on ubuntu server.In windows it was running successfully

Comment: have you got any further with this?

Comment: Is Jenkins using the same maven and JDK as in the command line?